# Reading in multiple integers from the scanner and assigning each integer to a different variable?

Tags: java

I have to read in integers and the scanner has to continue to scan them in until 0 is entered. Then all of those numbers have to be saved to different variables. Then the variables have to be compared and the following has to occur:

- Find the smallest integer
- Find how many integers are even
- Find the sum of the negative integers

I have this so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter integers");
    do
    {

    }
    while (in.nextInt() !=0);
}
```

I am lost on what to do next.

Comment: So really you haven't done any work and expect us to do it for you. I see.

Comment: The very next thing I would do is to **assign the scanned integer to a variable**... Then you can find it it's smaller than the smallest you already have, if it's even, and sum it to another variable if it's negative...

Comment: next, you should complete the code. what have you seen in your classes? chances are, you'll need to use those. Anyway, in order to find the smallest integer, or to find out how many are even, or the sum of the negative integers, you don't have to store them all.

Comment: I understand I have to assign the value to a variable but I do not know how to incorporate a loop to continue to scan in integers and assign it to variables until 0 has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues here, which would be solved if you read the [docs for Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Please don't expect people here to simply write your code for you. I'm doing this as an exception.

Your goal is to get the smallest integer, the number of even integers, and the sum of the negative integers. The code will stop running once the number 0 is entered.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter integers");
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // init to max possible
    int numEven = 0;
    int sumNeg = 0;
    while (true) {
        int val = in.nextInt(); 
        if(val == 0) // stop if 0 is entered
            break;

        // check small
        min = Math.min(val, min);

        // check even
        if(val % 2 == 0)
            evenNum++;

        // sum negatives
        if(val < 0)
            sumNeg += val;
    }
}
```